# Best way to handle asynchronous tasks with flask

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous

I have seen a lot of different things about redis, rabbitmq, kafka etc. but even with that I don't really understand what would be the best use in my case.

I have a flask app that will be deployed. In this app, each user will send their own requests, potentially at the same time. From this request, I'll have to run different python functions taking 1 to 10 minutes, and once it is done, update the database to give the user his content.

What is the best system to do that, knowing that the created content will not be too big (an element is up to 10000 string characters, and each user creates max ~200 elements/month) ?

Thanks in advance I hope that I was clear enough !

Comment: I'd use something like websockets to update the client app when the task is finished. Or you could fetch every N seconds to check for updates if you don't want to use websockets.

Comment: You could accept HTTP requests via a load balancer then write to Kafka... External Kafka Consumers outside of your Flask app could then process that request to pull load away from the HTTP server. Then you can use tools like Kafka Connect to write to a database... None of this "requires Python", and can be framework independent.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, You will need to implement an load balancing system on your server, Also It must have to multiprocessing/multithreading features. You must select ngnix web server for this project.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply ! Yes of course I know that I will need to use multiprocessing/threading and a corresponding server. The thing is that I want first to test it locally before deploying it. Do you think that I must first try without multi or already use multi in my tests ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using FastAPI instead of Flask however... the syntax is pretty similar so it's not a big leap...

FastAPI is built from the ground up with asynchronous programming in mind. It is based on the asyncio library and makes use of Python's async and await keywords, which makes it easier to write efficient and scalable code for handling requests and responses.

Flask, on the other hand, is not designed for asynchronous programming, and while it does support some level of async programming, it requires more work to set up and use compared to FastAPI. Flask's reliance on traditional synchronous programming can lead to performance issues when handling large numbers of concurrent requests, while FastAPI's asynchronous architecture enables it to handle high traffic with ease.

FastAPI also provides built-in support for modern features like type annotations, automatic documentation generation, and data/request validation, which make it easier to write reliable and maintainable code.

Theres a good cookie-cutter example from the creator of FastAPI [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql). It may look daunting but you can remove all the frontend and unnecessary stuff and have a really nice starting point!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I honestly had never thought about that. Given the fact that except this last feature that I described in my question, do you think I still need to use fast api or it is okay if I continue with flask ? Because it seems that many companies user flask even if they obviously use asynchronous system, am I wrong ?

Comment: Flask is not specifically designed for asynchronous programming but it can still be used. Companies may use Flask because it is a well-established and popular framework with a large community of developers; i.e. lots of documentation, resources, and support available. However its worth noting that they are likely to have additional infrastructure in place to help with scaling and performance. (FastAPI is nice as you dont have to worry about that!)

If you're building an application that relies heavily on asynchronous programming,  FastAPI is likely a better fit!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer I think I'll continue with flask for now as I need to finish the v1 quickly and i will then look a more in depth at fastapi to potentially move the app. Thanks for the help !